# How to select only parent element when clicked of the same class

Tags: jquery, menu

I apologize for the lack of a better title.

I have a problem with a menu. I'll let the code explain.

```
<ul class="menu">
   <li>Item in 1</li>
   <li class="has-children">
       Item in 2
       <ul class="sub-menu">
           <li class="has-children">
               Item in 3 
               <ul class="sub-menu">
                   <li>Item in 4</li>
               </ul>
           </li>
       </ul>
   </li>
   <li>Item in 1</li>
   <li>Item in 1</li>
</ul>
```

I have a mobile menu with a structure as shown above. What I'm trying to do is have the 2nd level of menu toggle show when `<li class="has-children">` is clicked, while not showing the 3rd level item.

Then have the 3rd level item toggle show when the 2nd level `<li class="has-children">` is clicked.

Here's what I tried:

```
$('.menu').children('.has-children').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).children('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
});
```

The problem occurs when I click on the 2nd level `<li class="has-children">` in hopes to toggle the 3rd level item. But what happens instead is that the whole menu gets toggled back.

Here's the js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yb9khz6w/

Now I thought `.children()` only selects the direct sibling, why is the 2nd level menu triggering its parent?

Help anyone? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using 'on()';

```js
$(function() {
  $('.has-children').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children().slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Item in 1</li>
  <li class="has-children">Item in 2
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="has-children">Item in 3
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>Item in 4</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item in 1</li>
  <li>Item in 1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked! I didn't know about e.stopPropagation();

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your Javascript to:

```
$('.menu').on("click", ".has-children", function(e){
    $(this).children('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yb9khz6w/10/)

This is changing the event binding for the click to any of the `has-children` class within the `menu` class, which ensures that the reference to `this` in the Javascript relates to the `has-children` class item that was clicked.

The `e.stopPropagation()` ensures that the click on a `has-children` class doesn't propagate up to other instances of the `has-children` class that the clicked item may be contained in.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will work for you

```
$('.menu').on("click", ".has-children", function(e){
    $(this).children('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I chose the answer after you simply because of the live example.

Comment: @Bobby .. Its fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the fiddle [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/yb9khz6w/11/)

I think if you want to show the **item 4** on click of **Item 2** as well you can use

```
$(this).find('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
```

instead of

```
$(this).children('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
```

Hope it Helps ........